# Subtracting a variable not functioning

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys I'm having a small issue trying to get my variable to subtract 1 each time one of the images are click on, and once 5 have been selected no more can be clicked. But for some reason I can't seem to get this to work. If someone can see where i'm going wrong here that would be fantastic. Not really sure where i'm going wrong here, so I've commented out the code that's making it spit out the error.

Error Message:

> ReferenceError: battleship1Placement is not defined

Thanks in advance.

```js
function load() {
  //var numberOfShipsPlaced = 0;
  //var battleShip1Placement = 5;
}

function tileClicked(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);

  //document.getElementById("hud").innerHTML = "battleship1Placement: " + battleship1Placement;

  //if (numberOfShipsPlaced == 0) {
  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png') > -1) {
    //battleship1Placement - 1;

    //if (battleship1Placement > 0) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridShip.png'
    //}
  }
  //}
}

function hover(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);

  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png') > -1) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png'
  }
}

function unhover(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);

  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png') > -1) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png'
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="load()">
  <tr>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A1" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A2" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A3" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A4" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A5" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A6" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A7" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A8" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A9" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A10" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
  </tr>
  <p id="hud"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: leaving your code un-commented-out, and providing us the error message you're seeing, is going to be much more helpful than just telling us "I have a problem somewhere."  Please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update yours here, and it will be much easier to help you out.

Comment: First of all I didn't think the code was that complex that it even needed commenting. But I have updated the post with the error message.

Comment: You misunderstand his comment.  Why did you comment out the code that "causes the issue"?  It would be better if you didn't comment it out

Comment: The reason I put the comments in is to help identify where the error was occurring so that everyone doesn't have to find it themselves, I thought it would be simpler I guess next time I won't bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your variable `battleShip1Placement` to outside of the `load()` function because its scope is limited in `load()` function.

Also you are making your condition too complex and there is an typo error too as you have used `battleship1Placement` instead of `battleShip1Placement`...

I have made some changes in your `tileClicked()` function..

***Stack Snippet***

```js
function load() {}

var numberOfShipsPlaced = 0;
var battleShip1Placement = 5;
//battleShip1Placement < 1 || 
function tileClicked(img) {
  var lengthImg = document.querySelectorAll("img").length;
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);
  var imgSrc = img.getAttribute("src");
  //console.log(imgSrc);
  if ((imgSrc.includes("gridHover") || imgSrc.includes("gridDefault")) && battleShip1Placement > 0) {
    battleShip1Placement--;
    img.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridShip.png';
  } else if (imgSrc.includes("gridShip")) {
    battleShip1Placement++;
    img.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png';
  }
  document.getElementById("hud").innerHTML = "battleship1Placement: " + battleShip1Placement;
}

function hover(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);
  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png') > -1) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png'
  }
}

function unhover(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);
  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png') > -1) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png'
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="load()">
  <tr>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A1" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A2" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A3" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A4" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A5" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A6" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A7" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A8" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A9" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
    <th><img src="http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png" draggable="false" class="gridDefault" id="A10" onclick="tileClicked(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unhover(this)"></th>
  </tr>
  <p id="hud"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer it was very helpful.

Comment: This might be a stupid comment but is it just as easy to undo the clicked image and +1 to the variable?

Comment: @dannybots111 I have updated my answer by doing some changes in conditions...have a look..

Comment: Very helpful and understandable, I'm quite new to javascript but I think I'm slowly getting there. Would it be too much to ask for some assistance on one of my other questions as you seem to know what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable battleship1Placement is only defined within the scope of the load function. You can either make your variable global by putting it outside of a function, or put everything under one scope and use the variable within the scope.
See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp for more reference.

So it's either

```
var numberOfShipsPlaced = 0;
var battleShip1Placement = 5;

function load() {
}

function tileClicked(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);

  document.getElementById("hud").innerHTML = "battleship1Placement: " + battleship1Placement;

  if (numberOfShipsPlaced == 0) {
  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png') > -1) {
    battleship1Placement - 1;

    if (battleship1Placement > 0) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridShip.png'
    }
  }
  }
}

function hover(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);

  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png') > -1) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png'
  }
}

function unhover(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);

  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png') > -1) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png'
  }
}
```

or

```
(function () {
var numberOfShipsPlaced = 0;
var battleShip1Placement = 5;

function load() {
}

function tileClicked(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);

  document.getElementById("hud").innerHTML = "battleship1Placement: " + battleship1Placement;

  if (numberOfShipsPlaced == 0) {
  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png') > -1) {
    battleship1Placement - 1;

    if (battleship1Placement > 0) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridShip.png'
    }
  }
  }
}

function hover(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);

  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png') > -1) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png'
  }
}

function unhover(img) {
  var tagID = img.id;
  var img_el = document.getElementById(tagID);

  if (img_el.src.indexOf('http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridHover.png') > -1) {
    img_el.src = 'http://server2.sulmaxcp.com/Images/gridDefault.png'
  }
}
}());
```